# Varnish HTC status -1 Magento 2 Apache

Tags: apache, magento2, varnish

I need help in varnish issue. I have a script which takes around 30 minutes, we have setup varnish on server and currently the timeout is `.connect_timeout = 1800s;` but still i am getting 503 and the `FetchError = HTC status -1` which i am unable to find on any support channel.

Varnish is setup along with Apache and Magento below is the default.vcl

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 2700s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 3000s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 3000s;
#   .probe = {
#        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
#       .timeout = 2s;
#        .interval = 5s;
#        .window = 10;
#        .threshold = 5;
#   }
}

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
    "3.104.230.171";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
        return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch" || req.url ~ "sociallogin" || req.url ~ "/customer/account" || req.url ~ "/admin_q6xipl/admin/system_config" || req.url ~ "blog" || req.url ~ "events") {
        return (pass);
    }

if (req.url ~ "/admin_q6xipl/admin/system_config") {
        return (pipe);
    }


    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    #unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    #unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    #unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    #unset resp.http.Server;
    #unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    #unset resp.http.Via;
    #unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

/etc/default/varnish

```
# Configuration file for Varnish Cache.
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#
# Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  You will
# need to copy /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and
# edit that file.

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "no" to disable.
START=yes

# Set WARMUP_TIME to force a delay in reload-vcl between vcl.load and vcl.use
# This is useful when backend probe definitions need some time before declaring
# configured backends healthy, to avoid routing traffic to a non-healthy backend.
#WARMUP_TIME=0

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
#   -T localhost:6082 \
#   -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
#    -p thread_pool_min=1 \
#    -p thread_pool_max=1500 \
#    -p http_resp_hdr_len=250000 \
#    -p http_resp_size=282759 \
#    -p http_max_hdr=128 \
#    -p listen_depth=1024 \
#    -p lru_interval=900 \
#    -p connect_timeout=1800 \
#    -p max_restarts=6 \
#    -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#    -s malloc,1536m"

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"

VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
```

/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator

[Service]
Type=forking

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232

# On systemd >= 228 enable this to avoid "fork failed" on reload.
#TasksMax=infinity

# Maximum size of the corefile.
LimitCORE=infinity

# Set WARMUP_TIME to force a delay in reload-vcl between vcl.load and vcl.use
# This is useful when backend probe definitions need some time before declaring
# configured backends healthy, to avoid routing traffic to a non-healthy backend.
#WARMUP_TIME=0

#ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -p http_max_hdr=256 -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -p http_max_hdr=256 -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here attached is the screenshot for reference.

[image]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/508ae8bc149d3ad338d227a04ddc030e2045105b/include/tbl/htc.h#L41, the `HTC -1` fetch error you see in your *VSL output*, is an `Unexpected end of input` error.

This means that it's not Varnish who is giving up, but rather the backend itself.

You might want to take a look at your webserver logs, or webserver timeout settings.